# How to generate an ASP.NET 2.0 (retro) web.config within Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I'm using VS 2010 Express Edition (VWD) to develop a website project that will be deployed to a Windows 2000 Server (targeting .NET 2.0).

BACKGROUND: The website was new, so I chose the 'c# blank website' project template in VS 2010. This (as you may know) gave me an extremely more lean web.config file than VS 2008. I like that for 4.0 development, but I'm going to be deploying it to the testing region tomorrow and I'm getting concerned that all that extra stuff that used to be in the web.config is going to bite me. From what I have read ([ASP.NET 4 Whitepaper](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429239); Scott Gu's Blog: weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/clean-web-config-files-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) the "gunk" was removed because 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 were built on the same runtime and kept needing extra stuff at the application level since they shared the machine.config. But, that implies 2.0 runtime sites needed those extra sections and configurations.

So, if my 2.0 web project is going to be using the 2.0 machine.config, is there a way to have Visual Studio generate the handlers, tag sections, config sections, etc. that were omitted in the 'blank website' template? Since it is pre IIS 7, I don't need the IIS 7 specific sections.

Thanks for your help,

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

You can easily target the [framework of your choice](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/20/vs-2008-multi-targeting-support.aspx).  It has been supported since VS2008.

Comment: Maybe not in Web Developer Express Edition? I don't see it on this screenshot I just took: http://cid-796969fa8dd35014.photos.live.com/self.aspx/Public%20Misc/VWD%20Exp%20New%20Website%20Screenshot.png?lc=1033